# How can I break up a Haskell statement when the type of a parameter is not static?

Tags: haskell

This is a bit difficult to explain, but I've run into this situation a few times.

The code is as follows:

```
work :: String -> IO ()
work a = do
  input <- lines <$> getContents
  sortF <- let f = flip sortByM input
    in case a of
        "name" -> f (return . id         :: FilePath -> IO FilePath)
        "time" -> f (getModificationTime :: FilePath -> IO UTCTime)
        _ ->      f (getModificationTime :: FilePath -> IO UTCTime)
  print sortF

sortByM :: (Monad m, Ord a) => (b-> m a) -> [b] -> m [b]
sortByM f x = do
  x' <- mapM f x
  return $ fst <$> (sortBy (comparing snd) $ zip x x')
```

The above throws an error of:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘UTCTime’ with ‘[Char]’
  Expected type: String -> IO FilePath
    Actual type: FilePath -> IO UTCTime
• In the first argument of ‘f’, namely
    ‘(getModificationTime :: FilePath -> IO UTCTime)’
  In the expression:
    f (getModificationTime :: FilePath -> IO UTCTime)
  In a case alternative:
      "time" -> f (getModificationTime :: FilePath -> IO UTCTime)
```

Which makes sense, but is there a way to somehow achieve the above? Otherwise I have to do the below, which feels less maintainable:

```
work :: String -> IO ()
work a = do
  input <- lines <$> getContents
  sortF <- case a of
        "name" -> flip sortByM input (return . id         :: FilePath -> IO FilePath)
        "time" -> flip sortByM input (getModificationTime :: FilePath -> IO UTCTime)
        _ ->      flip sortByM input (getModificationTime :: FilePath -> IO UTCTime)
  print sortF

sortByM :: (Monad m, Ord a) => (b-> m a) -> [b] -> m [b]
sortByM f x = do
  x' <- mapM f x
  return $ fst <$> (sortBy (comparing snd) $ zip x x')
```

Comment: Does `let f x = sortByM x input` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running into the [Dreaded Monomorphism Restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction). Due to issues with optimisation and code generation, when GHC sees a value that doesn't have explicit arguments it will infer a monomorphic type for it rather than the more general polymorphic type you would expect.

You can either disable the restriction using the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` pragma, or you can give `f` an explicit parameter:

```
sortF <- let f xs = sortByM xs input in ...
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it suffice to give `f` a type signature?

Comment: That would work, but it also means tangling with the type variable scoping rules, which I didn't want to get into (because I barely understand them myself). In this case that wouldn't be a problem, but if the top level function was polymorphic and you wanted to use those variables in the type of "f" then it would get hairy.

Comment: `ScopedTypeVariables` should have been part of the language…

Answer (score 1):

Making some assumptions about what you want... there tends to be lots of options on code structure.  You can have a sum type (not a great solution here):

```
  ...
  sortF <- let f = flip sortByM input
    in case a of
        "name" -> Left <$> f (return . id         :: FilePath -> IO FilePath)
        "time" -> Right <$> f (getModificationTime :: FilePath -> IO UTCTime)
        _ ->      Right <$> f (getModificationTime :: FilePath -> IO UTCTime)
  either print print sortF
```

Since the only thing you really know about a "multi-typed" `sortF` is that it is an instance of `Show` you can just call `show` and use `String`:

```
  ...
  sortF <- let f = flip sortByM input
    in show <$> case a of
        "name" -> f (return . id         :: FilePath -> IO FilePath)
        "time" -> f (getModificationTime :: FilePath -> IO UTCTime)
        _ ->      f (getModificationTime :: FilePath -> IO UTCTime)
  putStrLn sortF
```

And you can use a more function-oriented approach in combination with unifying the type to `String`:

```
  ...
  let op | a == "name" = return . show
         | otherwise   = fmap show . getModificationTime
      f x = sortByM x input
  putStrLn =<< f =<< op
```